# PHP How to Implode This Multiple Array?

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry guys, I am new in programmer and I am stuck in this code, I want to implode this array and get result like this: Action, Adventure, Comedy, Science Fiction

> $input = Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [id] => 28
>         [name] => Action
>     )
>
> [1] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [id] => 12
>         [name] => Adventure
>     )
>
> [2] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [id] => 35
>         [name] => Comedy
>     )
>
> [3] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [id] => 878
>         [name] => Science Fiction
>     )
> ```
>
> )

I am trying do like this and always getting error messages:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry['name'];
}, $input));
```

or

```
echo implode(', ', array_column($input, 'name'));
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `return $entry->name;` -  the sub-items are objects, not arrays.

Comment: `array_column()` works just fine on an array of objects.  You may have had an outdated PHP version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should work. I have changed the return of the anonymous function to return the objects name property instead of an array entry.

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
    return $entry->name;
}, $input));
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.  What did you change? Why does it work? What was wrong with the original code?

Comment: Second that! Not an actual answer.